# Grails: master domain field by detail domain field [hasMany]

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm, dsl

There are domains:

```
class Order {
  static hasMany = [execDepartments: Department]
  String orderNo
  //boolean signature 
  ...
}

class Department {
  String name
  ...
}
```

I want to add *boolean signature* field for Order but by Department, so I need field signature by execDepartments for Order. Is it possible? Please help.

Comment: signature must belongs to Order not Department, each Order has signature for each Department. Each orders must have many departments with its signatures. @VictorSergienko

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this an m:m relationship?

why not create another domain like

```
class Order {
  static hasMany = [execDepartments: DepartmentOrder]
  String orderNo
  //boolean signature 
  ...
}

class DepartmentOrder{
    boolean signature
    Order order
    Department department
}

class Department {
    String name
    static hasMany = [execOrders: DepartmentOrder]
}
```

Then you can write the belongTo

Comment: I know this way, but thought some other simple way exists or not. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a list of signatures in the `Order` domain. 
Possibly an `OrderSignature` domain that maps signatures to orders.

Comment: signature must be belongs to Order not Department, each Order has signature for each Department. Each orders must have many departments with signatures.

Comment: But I have to join OrderSignature also with Department, how can i do it. @gotomanners